# libgdx updating scene when app goes invisible

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libgdx's render() function to update scene with time delta, and then draw the scene. However, when the app goes invisible, the render() function is no longer being called, which causes the scene to stop updating, E.g., an animation will stuck at the last frame, until app goes back to foreground.

The problem is that I am building an online real-time game which cannot be 'paused' on client. When the app switches to background, the game must keep updating the scene even without drawing the scene, so that when the user switches back to the app, he can see the most up-to-date scene, instead of a pause-and-resume scene that lags back.

My question is how to achieve this in libgdx, so that the scene keeps updating even when app goes background? Does anyone experience the same problem as mine?

Comment: Is the game logic run from the server? Can the game just pull all the updated data from the server once it resumes? It seems you would need to do something like this anyway, since Android often kills games in the background to reclaim memory.

Comment: The user experience would hurt if the game logic is pulled when app goes foreground because of network delay. The game is real-time, so timing is critical. E.g., when the game goes foreground, the game must be smart enough to 'catch up' and sync any animations / graphics at the current frame to make sure this player is seeing what other players are seeing at the moment.

Comment: Another problem with libgdx is in the app, when the libgdx view is invisible (e.g., hide the view, and show another normal Android view on top of it), the render thread stops rendering, which stops scene updating. I looks like I have to rely on my own threading to do the scene updating so it keeps updating regardless of app / view state, and allow libgdx to render when it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Libgdx app, the render thread is only invoked when rendering, thus only when it has the screen.  For most games this is the only time the game should be doing any computations, so combining the update and render makes a lot of sense.

In Android, an app generally only gets CPU cycles assigned to it by the OS when its "foreground".  To run an app in the background requires using a different platform API (See, for example, https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html.)  Simply creating additional threads will not be sufficient to keep your app running in the background (the OS may decide to terminate it completely if it wants the RAM back for something else).

Generally, users do not expect an Android application to continue running (and using battery) when not in the foreground.

Additionally, even if your app is coded to run in the background correctly, when the foreground app is using the CPU significantly, your background app may not be run.

You can hook into the suspend and resume events to pause your game and then "fast-forward" your game state as necessary.  Or, do your computations in the cloud if you require that they run in real-time.

Comment: The ideal way is to make real-time computation in cloud, and sync to client when it goes foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your scene from other thread if it doesn't need GL context in it.

Or you can override onPause() method in your AndroidApplication class in Android projects, and keep using render() method for updating.
In onPause() method of AndroidApplication graphics are told to stop rendering.

Maybe you can create interface class to update your scene, without constant rendering when the app is paused, concerning the battery life.

This is the code from onPause() method.
Maybe this will lead you to correct solution.

```
@Override
protected void onPause () {
    boolean isContinuous = graphics.isContinuousRendering();
    graphics.setContinuousRendering(true);
    graphics.pause();

    input.onPause();

    if (isFinishing()) {
        graphics.clearManagedCaches();
        graphics.destroy();
    }
    graphics.setContinuousRendering(isContinuous);

    graphics.onPauseGLSurfaceView();

    super.onPause();
}
```